# Android, java String.trim() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, exception, trim

Analyzing my Android app crashes, I found a weird one that happens only on Samsung Galaxy Note 3 devices. Here is the top of crash stack:

```
-------
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
java.lang.String.trim(String.java:1416)
-------
```

Does anyone know how it can be possible?

It looks like manufacturer slightly updated original version of String class.

Comment:
The problem is that String object is immutable - I can not modify internal chars array or string length in any way. That's why trim() method in theory should never throw such type of exceptions: trim() method must check array bounds by itself (that it really does in default implementation).

Comment: you access extra array index which is not present ...........

Comment: is it ok on other devices except samsung note3

Comment: Have you tried on other devices also ??

Comment: post the appropriate code. even the full logcat.

Comment: Yes, trim() method works fine on other devices.The problem is that java String is immutable, so I just can not access extra array index by invoking trim() method.

Comment: Post the code with stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make your own version of `trim()` if you want to ensure that it is 100% vendor-independent.

Here's what the Oracle JDK version of `trim()` looks like:

```
public String trim() {
    int len = value.length;
    int st = 0;
    char[] val = value;    /* avoid getfield opcode */

    while ((st < len) && (val[st] <= ' ')) {
        st++;
    }
    while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ')) {
        len--;
    }
    return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length)) ? substring(st, len) : this;
}
```

The `value` in the above fragment is the `char[]` of the `String`

Comment: Probably I will. I just want to make sure I didn't miss anything.